# .NET Core C# web API integration testing an inmemory database

Tags: c#, .net-core, automated-tests

I'm currently trying to create an integration test for my .NET Core Web API.
I'm following the advice here:
https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/how-to-test-your-csharp-web-api

When I run my test to check the HttpStatusCode 'Should' 'Be' ok, the test is failing BUT the test does pass if I use the '/weatherforecast' example that comes with the .NET Core Web API template. If I use my project, the test fails. Is this because I have no values created in the DB when I start the app? How do I create those values? The code for my test is below:

```
            [Fact]
    public async Task Get_Should_Retrieve_Score()
    {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync("/diceroll");
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        //var DiceRoll = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DiceRoll[]>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        //forecast.Should().HaveCount(0);
    }
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: Can't say anything without looking at your API code..

Comment: Which part of the API do you want to see, specifically?

Comment: The error is a Status word in the Response data.  Do create a test model you should have a test sever that send back various response messages.  Your test will first set variable in the server that tells server what error to generate and then you tell client to make a new connection to the test server.

Comment: The one for which the test fails...

Comment: What Status Code _do_ you get instead?

Comment: @Fildor I get a 'NotFound' StatusCode.

Comment: So, it's a 404 ... Can you reach that endpoint through other means? Browser? cUrl? PostMan?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple test this way:

```
public class WeatherForecastControllerTests: 
IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Api.Startup>>
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public 
    WeatherForecastControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Api.Startup> 
    fixture)
    {
        Client = fixture.CreateClient();
    }
}

public class WeatherForecastControllerTests: 
IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Api.Startup>>
{
    readonly HttpClient _client { get; }

    public 
    WeatherForecastControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Api.Startup> 
    fixture)
    {
         _client = fixture.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_Should_Retrieve_Forecast()
    {
         var response = await _client.GetAsync("/weatherforecast");
         response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);

         var forecast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherForecast[]> 
         (await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
         forecast.Should().HaveCount(5);
    }
}
```

Here you have an example how to test it.

https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/how-to-test-your-csharp-web-api